# WPF DataGrid MultiBinding to Class in the DataGrid's ItemSource

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

This is my first WPF application.  I currently have a DataGrid that is bound to an entity framework object. This object contains a class as one of its items for a contact (First Name, middle, etc).

So my question is: How do you use MultiBinding on a data column using the elements of that class?

Here is the code.  I am trying to bind the Contacts name using a converter.  The converter displays the name based on the parameter passed.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
    x:Name="GridResult" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    MinHeight="{Binding DataGridMinHeight}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
    BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkBlueBrush}"
    BorderThickness="0 1 0 0"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderCenter}">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridResult, Path=SelectedItem.AssistanceId}" />  
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameColumn" 
                Binding="{Binding LinkName}" 
                Header="Reference" 
                Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CompanyColumn" 
                Binding="{Binding Company.CompanyName}" 
                Header="Company"
                Width="Auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ContactColumn" 
                Header="Contact"
                Width="Auto" > 
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}" ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst" >
                            <Binding Source="Contact" Path="Salutation"/>
                            <Binding Source="Contact" Path="FirstName"/>
                            <Binding Source="Contact" Path="MiddleName"/>
                            <Binding Source="Contact" Path="LastName"/>
                            <Binding Source="Contact" Path="Suffix"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>    
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

EDIT: ADDING PHOTO OF RESULT
[image: Search Result]

Comment: does `<Binding Path="Contact.Salutation"/>` works?

Comment: @Bijan Just tried that.  No it did not.  My converter said the object was null.

Comment: so the contact object is null. you can avoid seeing `unsetvalue` with adding `FallbackValue=""` to bindings

Comment: @Bijan I can see in the debugger in the Autos window that the returned results do have a complete "Contact" object.  It's just not getting to the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  Instead of trying to pass each element of the Contact Class to the MultiBinding, just pass the class itself.  Then use the converter to access the class elements (i.e. First name, Last, etc) to return the desired output string.

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ContactColumn" 
    Header="Contact"
    Width="Auto"
    >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameConverter}" ConverterParameter="LastNameFirst">
            <Binding Path="Contact"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```